# IE7 - <button> does not submit form

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

How can I make a  tag in IE7 submit the form, while doing all the form validation that is setup on the form?

if I just do a `document.forms[0].submit();` it submits, but ignores form validation.

**Edit**:
Everybody likes telling me to use the input tag... That will sumbit the form but wont work in my situation which is why i asked about the button tag...

```
<form action="my/script" onsubmit="return ValidateFunc();">
<button> <img src="image/do_this_with_input_tag.png"> Some Text </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using a `<button type="submit">`?

Comment: @Nick Craver: If my memory serves me correctly that's the default type in IE, but not the other browsers.

Comment: @Justin808: I think we need to see more of your code to help you.

Comment: You should be using an `<input>` tag. Anything you can accomplish with `<button>` tag can be achieved with an `<input>` and some CSS.

Comment: @meager no it can't.  You can't paragraphs of text, a heading and some text, a table, an image (with alt text), a numbered list etc into an <input> whereas all this is possible with <button>

Comment: @Justin: Nick basically already gave you the answer in his comment. What did you actually mean with "Nope. Doesn't submit" comment?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, when I added the type="submit" attribute to the button tag, clicking it did nothing, same as without the attribute. -- Well reading Suresh as well as Nick, I'll try the attribute again when I get back to the office.

Comment: You can also use the <input type="image" src="image/do_this_with_input_tag.png"> [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input) It works the same as submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used jquery to submit the button. If i use straight javascript if bypasses the validation setup. Jquery 's form submit runs the validation before submitting.

After additional research, the  tag, even with a type="submit" cannot submit a form in older version of IE.

Comment: I have tested type="submit" on ie7, seems to submit the form fine for me.

Answer (score 9):

First have a button with type submit as

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

In your form tag, include the onsubmit() event as

```
<form
     action="/path/to/server/side/script"
     name="testform" 
     onsubmit="return validate()"
     >
```

The `validate()` function should return `true` if the form validation goes through or a `false` if the validation fails.
e.g.

```
function validate(){
   if(...){//valid
      return true;    
   }else{//not valid
      return false;
   }    
}
```

**EDIT:**
Always specify the button type. If not specified, in IE it defaults to "button" while in Chrome and Firefox it defaults to "submit".

```
<form action="my/script" onsubmit="return ValidateFunc();">
<button type="submit"> <img src="image/do_this_with_input_tag.png"> Some Text </button>
</form>
```

And in future, include more details in your question if you want proper answers.

Comment: This is exactly how things work, with the INPUT tag, not so much with the BUTTON tag.

Comment: I'll try the type="submit" attribute again once I get back into the office.

Comment: For security also validate on the server, in case the user disables Javascript (Noscript) or doesn't even use a browser (Fiddler/Charles etc). I can't stress that enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this simply by adding `type="submit"` to the button.

`<button>Submit</button>` was not submitting in IE7.

`<button type="submit">Submit</button>` does submit in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the Validation only recognize a "submit" event from a "submit" button.

You should use a "submit" input instead of a "button" input. Then the validation mechanism will be able to intercept the submit event. you can call form.submit within the validation.submit function.

Here's the code:

```
<form id="theForm">
   ...
   <input type="submit" value="submitMe"/>
</form>
```

in Javascript:

```
$('#theForm').validate({
    ...
    submitHandler: function() {
        // do some trick here
        ...
        // submit the form
        $('#theForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using (dummy/not visible) input field inside form positioned absolute with this css:

```
<input class="dummy" type="submit" />

.dummy {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    font-size:0px;
    line-height:0px;
}
```

Just avoid using display:none or visibility:hidden or width:0px etc. Use only this css i have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IE11 with a submit button inside another form:

```
<form id="form1">
  ...
</form>
<form id="form2">
  ...
    <button type="submit" form="form1">OLA KE ASE</button>
  ...
</form>
```

You can solve it usign javascript, i did it with jQuery on a generic way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr('form') != '') {
            document.getElementById($(this).attr('form')).submit();
        }
    });
});
```