# Button HTML will not submit form in IE7

Tags: forms, button, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone let me know why this form will not submit in IE7?

```
<form id="orderform" name"orderForm" action="http://www.mydomain.com/secure/delivery-details.html" method="post">
<a  id="add">+</a>
 <table id="ordertable" width="533" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="titles">
      <td style="width:100px">Code (e.g 66203)</td>
      <td style="width:100px">Mtrs (e.g 10)</td>
      <td style="width:100px">Order Line Ref.</td>
      <td>Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode"><input type="text" name="prodcode[]" id="prodcode" class="trigger" /></td>
      <td class="meterage"><input type="text" name="meterage[]" id="meterage" /></td>
      <td class="orderlineref"><input type="text" name="orderlineref[]" id="orderlineref" /></td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE7 - <button> does not submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020187/ie7-button-does-not-submit-form)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>`

Comment: @Andy Do not forget to accept the answer of the question. Thanks

Comment: I won't :)  But there is a time limit, ill need to do it shortly - 11 mins to be precise :)

Answer (score 1):

the button itself will not work because it has no action associated. the right HTML type for the object is

```
<input type="submit" name="submitter" value="Submit"/>
```

this way, the browser will know what to do when you click the button